# Command on ssh through uwsgi and django app

Tags: python, django, nginx, ssh, uwsgi

i want to execute the uwsgi (to serve a Django App through Nginx) so i've created the unix user (my_user) and i've created the ssh keys to connect with other server. So when i try to run a command through a terminal, all works. But.. when i try to send the same command through Django, i get an error:

```
SSHException at /utility/status/
No authentication methods available
```

I've configured uwsgi with the correct uid and gid.
Any suggestions?

I run uwsgi with the root user (that can run the command on ssh too). If i run the uwsgi with the "my_user", all works! Why?

Comment: I think you should try generating ssh key for your root user and add them to your ssh-server.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Fian, but the ssh key is present and as i wrote, if i launch a command on ssh with root, it works. It's all a little bit strange.